# grub.efi doesn't boot but shim.efi does

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

I have dual boot(Ubuntu 14.10 with windows8.1) I had got **grub rescue>unknown file system** and I used `boot-repair` to solve it. I removed the grub files and `boot-repair` gave some codes that I ran on terminal. At last I rebooted and again got unknown file system, I selected random options in boot order and got **shim.efi** along with **grub.efi**. I selected on **shim.efi** and it booted properly into Ubuntu 14.10. I want **shim.efi** to be default to save me the hassle next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your default boot order with the `efibootmgr` command in a Terminal window. Specifically, use the `-v` option to see the options that are available and then use the `-o` option to change the order. The whole process might look something like this:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0009,000D,0003,0001,0002,0004
Boot0000* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(1,800,112800,a8d39218-44ce-455b-8735-919754df131d)File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0001* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive BIOS(81,0,00)
Boot0002* UEFI:Removable Device BIOS(82,0,00)
Boot0003* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell  Vendor(5023b95c-db26-429b-a648-bd47664c8012,)..BO
Boot0004* UEFI:Network Device   BIOS(83,0,00)
Boot0009* UEFI OS   HD(1,800,112800,a8d39218-44ce-455b-8735-919754df131d)File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)..BO
Boot000D* ubuntu    HD(1,800,112800,a8d39218-44ce-455b-8735-919754df131d)File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)..BO
$ sudo efibootmgr -o D,9,0
```

Of course, your details will be different. The computer from which I cut-and-pasted this output has no Shim binary installed, so there's no such option here. You'll have to look for the Shim binary you're launching and set it first. You may optionally include other values as fallbacks. In fact, if there's an entry for Windows or some other OS that boots successfully, it's best to include it in the list so that it will boot even if Shim fails for some reason (say, if its file is accidentally deleted).